# Setup: C++ in VS Code under Linux (tasks.json and launch.json)

Tags: c++, json, linux, visual-studio-code

How to configure VS Code launch.json for C++ development under Linux?

The official documentation does not provide a launch.json sample[official documentation for WSL](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl).

Unfortunately, I can not get a succesful build and debug configuration of `tasks.json` and `launch.json` for "pure Linux/no WSL".

I am looking for recent versions of the two files, that are as generic as possible (use variables wherever possible in the json-files).

My current `c_cpp_properties.json`:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? You just said "Unfortunately I have troubles" which doesn't really tell us what's wrong.

Comment: You are right, I should have been more precise...thx for downvoting ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this `.vscode/launch.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++ build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "g++ build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

And `.vscode/tasks.json`:

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                // "cwd": "/usr/bin"
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: why is cwd in task.json is /usr/bin and not ${workspacefolder}?