# VSCode The terminal could not be started (exit code -1)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gcc, vscode-tasks

I'm trying to build a basic OpenGL program to display a window in Arch Linux and i get this terminal output in VSCode:

```
> Executing task: C/C++: g++ compile active file <

Compiling started...
/usr/bin/gcc -fdiagnostics-color=always -g -std=c++17 -I./include src/gltest.cpp > 
src/glad.c -o $SourceFolder/test spawn /bin/sh ENOENT

The build was completed with errors.
The terminal could not be started (exit code -1).
```

**So my question is: what does exit code -1 stand for in this case, and what is the reason of this issue?**

I want to be able to see the errors in the vscode terminal, just like running in bash.

Please note that this is a translation so it may not be 100% accurate to the expected output, I figured that if I asked this in english I'd have a higher chance of getting my question awnsered. I did not mess with the order of outputs or any values, just the text.

**Edit:** For some context, i'm following this guide:
[LearnOpenGL - Hello Window](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Window)
with the following
[tasks.json](https://github.com/JophiMa/questions)

executing this as a command in bash returns the following result:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find spawn: file or directory not found
/usr/bin/ld: /bin/sh: environ: invalid version 2 (max 0)
/usr/bin/ld: /bin/sh: error adding symbols: bad value
collect2: Error: ld returned 1 as its final status
```

Comment: The key words are "The build was completed with errors". So what are you going to start running in the terminal?

Comment: The issue was a faulty tasks.json, i recommend reading this thread:[Setup: C++ in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56406292/setup-c-in-vs-code-under-linux-tasks-json-and-launch-json)